# Looking for the best practice with SVN / GIT for Magento projects

Tags: svn, git, magento, github

We are a small team, 5 people now (2 dev, 1 project manager, 1 webdesign, 1 integrator) and we are working on Magento since 1&half years.

We must jump a new stage because we have new projects and 3 new people will join our team for dev/int and at this time some mistakes can append because we work on the same files.

Also, deployment takes us too much time.

We're efficient in our domain but not (apache, SSH, etc) in how to build a good SVN / repository process between our development serveur and production server...to develop and maintain what we build with magento.

We're on Macosx and we search the best SVN tools / method / feedback / tuto to develop and maintain our websites.
we read a lot of different things about that.
We're very interested about Github for mac or Tower, Gitbox etc... but we don't know how to build a good architecture like this :

- 1 local (Ubuntu actually but can be an other one)  or online environment for 7-8 users with different access rights (only /app/code/local / lib/js/ or just for /Skin/)
- a good step by step to publish on  :

  - 1 production environment (a different one = hosting company)

if we can do this we'll build a distinct dev or staging environment.

Thanks if someone could give me some tricks or good tutorial links.

Answer (score 2):

From time to time similar questions come up. Take a look at these:

- [Magento & Subversion (SVN) - Getting a Development Environment Started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058617/magento-subversion-svn-getting-a-development-environment-started/2064637#2064637)
- [Whats a good way to approach a development environment when working with Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481538/whats-a-good-way-to-approach-a-development-environment-when-working-with-magento/5486126#5486126)
- [Magento staging and production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913761/magento-staging-and-production/4915310#4915310)

I'm not voting this question as a duplicate of any of those because I want to hear someone talk more about Git[hub] on Magento projects.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe